# When to tell Bubble Sort is Finished JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

So I'm trying to write a bubble sort visualization in javascript and I'm not sure how to write the condition that must be met in order to break the loop. I know that each element from arr[0] to arr[length-1] must be less than the following element but if my array of data has like 10000 elements a statement like this won't work (obviously);

```
if(arr[0] < arr[1] < ...arr[length - 1]){
   return;
}
```

so how do I meet this condition? I know that the first element must be the smallest and the last must be the biggest but that does not mean its completely sorted and I can't figure out a way to terminate my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops. You must iterate through the list n squared times in order to perform the bubble sort algorithm. There are plenty of examples out there such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51908846/13008210

Comment: Oh okay, is this related to it being pretty slow because its o notation is O(n^2)? Also does this guarantee that the array will be completely sorted, if so how?

Comment: Consider the a case where the smallest element is in the place that the largest element belong (e.g. [2,3,4,5,1]. This element will get moved to the left once per iteration. So, after the first iteration it would be [2,3,4,1,5] and so on. This means it will take n - 1 iterations (of the inner loop) to move the element to its proper place. This is the worst case scenario for an element so we know it will never take more than n iterations to get an element into its proper place.

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you very much for helping me understand it better!