# How to get ID of collection in Firestore with angular Firestore

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm not able to get the ID of the document when I query a Firestore Database this way :

Could you give me some help ?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection  } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-annonces-contactees',
  templateUrl: './annonces-contactees.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./annonces-contactees.page.scss'],
})
export class AnnoncesContacteesPage implements OnInit {
  private annoncesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  annonces: Observable<Item[]>;
    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.annoncesCollection = afs.collection('annonces', ref => ref.where('prix', '>=', 1000000))
      this.annonces = this.annoncesCollection.valueChanges();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Comment: Try this..

this.annoncesCollection..snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
    }))

Comment: Thanks but how to display it in my html code ?
Now I'm using this to get results : 
 <li *ngFor="let annonce of annonces | async">
    {{ annonce.prix }}
  </li>

Comment: here is the example 'https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges'

Comment: Are you sure of your code ? I get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give you an example of how I dot it:
Let us suppose I have collection of hospitals and each hospital has its name,phone and location.

```
  constructor(private firestore:AngularFirestore){}
  hospitalsArray=[];
  ngOnInit(){
      this.firestore.collection("hospitals").snapshotChanges().subscribe((data) => {
        this.hospitalsArray = data.map(e => {
          return { id: e.payload.doc.id, location: e.payload.doc.data()["location"], number: e.payload.doc.data()["phone"], name: e.payload.doc.data()["name"]}
        })
  }
```

"hospitals" is the name of the collection and this id is the id of the document.

So if you want to display in the html file

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let hospital of hospitalsArray">
<ion-label>{{hospital.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Hi,
Do you know how can I sort data by ID ?
When I don't use the where condition I get the result sorted by ID but the results are sorted randomly whis the Where condition..

Any idea ?

Comment: Actually I have never tried it, I don't know if there is a build in function used for arrays for sorting , if not try using some sorting algorithms. And also i am going to try to search for it.

Comment: But why would you want to sort an array by id??

Comment: I need sort an array buy date, but as I'm using "Where" it't not allowed to sort data using one other filed ("date"). So I try to sort my data by ID or Date in template directly.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can after filling the array you used to fill your data. To sort it depending on the field you want. Anyway what do you mean by "you are using where"??

Comment: I mean querying my datas with the Where condition.

Comment: Okay deal. Try after fetching you data and putting them in the array try sorting the array depending on the field you want. I mean after doing this.hospitalsArray=data.map()... Try soring the array then displaying it.

Comment: Sort the array in the ngOnInit function.

Comment: Then let me know what will happen

Comment: No problem, did you ever hear of sorting algorithms such as bubble sort...?

Comment: Try to see this. https://www.educba.com/bubble-sort-in-javascript/#:~:text=How%20does%20Bubble%20Sort%20work%20in%20JavaScript%3F%201,nd%20element%20with%203%20rd%20More%20items...%20

Comment: Or you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817334/javascript-bubble-sort

Comment: but instead of arr[i] use arr[i].date for example,try it and let me know what will happen

Comment: I'm trying... Will let you know.
Thanks for your help.