# How i can do bubble sort to array with object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a task to make array sorting through Bubble sort. I just can’t understand how exactly it is necessary to implement sorting of such an array, in which objects. Can someone helpme, pls. I need sorting by data.year.

```js
const [table, setTable] = useState([
  {
    text: "Пошел в свой первый класс",
    id: 0,
    data: {
      year: 2012,
      day: 25,
      month: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    text: "Поехал на чемпионат по бейсболу",
    id: 1,
    data: {
      year: 2018,
      day: 14,
      month: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    text: "Поступил в институт",
    id: 2,
    data: {
      year: 2007,
      day: 12,
      month: 4,
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Bubble Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817334/javascript-bubble-sort)

Comment: Why would you want to use Bubble Sort here? There are far more efficient, and easier sorting methods. Or is this a homework question? See also: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/263213)

Comment: I suggest to start building the algorithm first that handles normal numbers. For example: `[1,4,2,5,3,2]` then worry about the object aspect later.

Comment: Yes, homework. I have already done sorting with the sort() method, but I need a solution without sort().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the sorted array

```js
function bblSort(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j].data.year > arr[j + 1].data.year) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return(arr);
}


var arr = [
  {
    text: "Пошел в свой первый класс",
    id: 0,
    data: {
      year: 2012,
      day: 25,
      month: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    text: "Поехал на чемпионат по бейсболу",
    id: 1,
    data: {
      year: 2018,
      day: 14,
      month: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    text: "Поступил в институт",
    id: 2,
    data: {
      year: 2007,
      day: 12,
      month: 4,
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: You missed the function call part

Comment: Yeah I just put the function.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the year instead of object in bubble sort algorithm

```js
//Bubble sort algorithm

const bubbleSort = array => {
  const arr = Array.from(array); // avoid side effects
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j].data.year > arr[j + 1].data.year) { //Added check inside object "data.year"
        [arr[j], arr[j + 1]] = [arr[j + 1], arr[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

const myArr = [
  {
    text: 'Пошел в свой первый класс',
    id: 0,
    data: {
      year: 2012,
      day: 25,
      month: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    text: 'Поехал на чемпионат по бейсболу',
    id: 1,
    data: {
      year: 2018,
      day: 14,
      month: 3
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Поступил в институт',
    id: 2,
    data: {
      year: 2007,
      day: 12,
      month: 4
    },
  },
] 

console.log(bubbleSort(myArr))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JS's .sort to sort it e.g. `...useState([...].sort((item1, item2) => item1.data.year - item2.data.year))` it takes a comparison function as it's first argument, if you don't pass any function it will try to sort it lexicographically.

But still it will do quick or merge sort depending on the size of the array.
If you want it to do a bubble sort for some reason you need to write the sort function manually.

About sorts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#examples

Comment: You missed part about `Bubble sort` in the question

Answer (score -1):

To sort objects by data.year in ascending order you should do it with `array.sort()` function:

```
arr.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.data.year - obj2.data.year);
```

The code above should do the sorting, now if you want to sort that array, then it obviously should update the state (unless you want to make new sorted array from that array)

```
setTable((prevTable) => [...prevTable.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.data.year - obj2.data.year)])
```

Comment: It looks like you completely missed the words about the need to use a specific sorting algorithm